# Contact form 7 call submit event in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I have a simple contact form and in the end I added a custom field:

```
<input type="text" name="test" id="test" class="form-control">
```

I need to check field is empty and then submit form:

```
$('.wpcf7-submit').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var testInput = $('input[name="test"]').val();

    if (testInput != '') {
        // How to submit form here?
    }
});
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First check if it's empty, then preventDefault. It will then submit otherwise

```
$('.wpcf7-submit').on('click', function (e) {
    var testInput = $('input[name="test"]').val();

    if (testInput === '') {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

EDIT:

You should also consider that people do not submit by pressing submit, but by pressing enter - therefore you should proably do something like this:

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function() {
  ....
}
```

Instead of listening to the click

Comment: it is submitting the page and reloading it while using e.preventDefault();

Comment: what do you mean with "while using" ? did you prevent the click or the submit?

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
$('.wpcf7-submit').submit();
```

Comment: The form is sent to Ajax

Answer (score 1):

you may preventDefault if the input is empty like so:

```
$('.wpcf7-submit').on('click', function (e) {
var testInput = $('input[name="test"]').val();

if (testInput === '') {
    e.preventDefault();

}
```

});

OR:

```
$('.wpcf7-submit').on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

var testInput = $('input[name="test"]').val();

if (testInput != '') {
    $('#form-id').submit();
}
```

});

Hope it will help.